# Ubuntu 13.10, bumblebee and power management problem

Tags: power-management, asus, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

First of all my laptop is asus n55sf with ubuntu 13.10.

I've installed bumblebee and it's working quite good (I've tried e.g. optirun firefox and it's working fine).

Right now I have problem with power management. In windows 7 my battery lasted for at least 3 hours and in ubuntu is more or less only 1 hour.

I'm not so advanced ubuntu user, so I need your help. Do I need to change some settings or install some additional software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of things that helps exceed time on battery was to use **Cpufreq Indicator**. It can be used for changing the CPU frequency on-the-fly.

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

Answer (score 2):

To preserve your battery install TLP from their ppa which can be found at www.linrunner.de/tlp on my ASUS i7 laptop, I get same life as on Windows 8

Comment: I've done that some time ago - I think it help a little bit, but it's still not the same time as on Windows.

Comment: Are you running all your programs with Optirun? In that case don't expect any battery life as the nvida card sucks good amount of power.

Comment: No, of course not;)

Comment: Thats strange as you should be getting the same consumption as Windows, can you do a sudo tlp-stat and tell me whats the wattage when battery is ON.

Comment: /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now  =  18524 [mW] ... are You asking for this?

Comment: Yep and its quite high,whats your brightness setting. Install powerstat and find out whats the culprit for your batt consumption.